# How to replace a paragraph between two or more keywords

Tags: awk, perl

I'm trying to replace a complete paragraph between keywords.

From this :

```
   port: 6666
    socks-port: 6699
    redir-port: 6669
    allow-lan: true
    mode: Rule
    log-level: info
    external-controller: 0.0.0.0:9090
    
    dns:
  enable: true
  ipv6: false
  # listen: 0.0.0.0:53
  # enhanced-mode: fake-ip
  nameserver:
    - 223.5.5.5
    - 114.114.114.114
  #  - 'tls://dns.rubyfish.cn:853'
  #fallback:
  #  - 'tcp://208.67.222.222:443'
  #  - 'tls://1.0.0.1:853'
  #  - 8.8.8.8
    proxies:
      - type: ss
        server: test.com
        
    proxy-groups:
    
      - name: Auto
        type: url-test
        proxies:
        - DATA:298.86GB DAYS:27
        
     - name: ⏲fallback
        type: fallback
        proxies: 
        - DATA:298.86GB DAYS:27
```

To this :

```
dns:
   enable: true
   enhanced-mode: redir-host # 或 fake-ip
   listen: 0.0.0.0:53
   nameserver:
      - 223.5.5.5
experimental:
   interface-name: Ethernet # 物理网卡名称
```

So basically all the things that comes after "Dns:" and before "proxies:" must be changed.
"proxies" will be repeated in the file, while "Dns:" only appears there.

I've tried using perl and use Inline::Files but if the content between DNS and Proxies changes it will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

If your replacement text is in `file1` and looks like this (last line added)

```
dns:
   enable: true
   enhanced-mode: redir-host # 或 fake-ip
   listen: 0.0.0.0:53
   nameserver:
      - 223.5.5.5
experimental:
   interface-name: Ethernet # 物理网卡名称
proxies:
```

Having played with this a little it appears that `sed` address ranges are non-greedy and so this works

```
sed -e "/^    proxies:/ r file1" -e "/dns:/,/proxies:/d" file
```

**Walkthrough**

`r`ead from `file1` and add it into to the original `file` after the match with `/^    proxies:/`

```
sed -e "/^    proxies:/ r file1"
```

Then reprocess the whole thing, capturing the range of lines from the first match `/dns:/` until `,` the first match with `/proxies:/` and `d`elete them

```
    -e "/dns:/,/proxies:/d" file
```

There is a useful resource on `sed` over at [grymoire](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37).

**EDIT update to comment**

The other `proxies:` lines are distinguished from your target by the 4 spaces at the beginning of the line (the others have more than 4). If you anchor the replacement to include `^`     then it will only pick up the one you are interested in so

```
sed -e "/^    proxies:/ r file1" -e "/dns:/,/proxies:/d" file
```

with my above insertion `file1` this yields

```
   port: 6666
    socks-port: 6699
    redir-port: 6669
    allow-lan: true
    mode: Rule
    log-level: info
    external-controller: 0.0.0.0:9090
    
dns:
   enable: true
   enhanced-mode: redir-host # 或 fake-ip
   listen: 0.0.0.0:53
   nameserver:
      - 223.5.5.5
experimental:
   interface-name: Ethernet # 物理网卡名称
proxies:
      - type: ss
        server: test.com
        
    proxy-groups:
    
      - name: Auto
        type: url-test
        proxies:
        - DATA:298.86GB DAYS:27
        
     - name: ⏲fallback
        type: fallback
        proxies: 
        - DATA:298.86GB DAYS:27
```

Comment: I've just tried it but there is an issue. He's adding it on the top AND replacing it where it supposed to. 
EDIT.  Your edit version seems to be working, not the first one. Or i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You probably have another blank line `^$` at the top of the file. Did you try the second version?

Comment: The second versions works perfecty, the first one will ALSO add the same replacement on the top of the file (so will have two time). And you are right the original file have a blank on the first line.

Comment: The deleted version inserted the new text at **every** blank line so if you have 2 blank lines in your original file `^$` then that would be the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks working perfectly, when you have time could you also describe the sed command step by step? I'm trying to learn Pearl,sed and awk. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry to bother i found out a problem. Apparently the word proxy comes in the file many times, so every time he encounter the word proxy it will do the script. 
The word "dns:" comes only in that point. If it's any useful external-controller: 0.0.0.0:9090 appears only that time also. I've update the file a little longer.

Answer (score 0):

Sed posixly we can achieve what is required.

```
sed -e '
  /dns:/,/proxies:/!b
  /dns:/r file1
  /proxies:/!d
' file
```

**Explanation:**

- Print as is lines outside the range.
- Range is dns lines begin to proxies end.
- Within the range, insert into stdout stream fir the dns line.
- Delete all lines in range except proxies
- Since the read command does not touch the pattern space so deleting dns will still print the read file file1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `file1` contains your replacement text:

```
$ cat file1
dns:
   enable: true
   enhanced-mode: redir-host # 或 fake-ip
   listen: 0.0.0.0:53
   nameserver:
      - 223.5.5.5
experimental:
   interface-name: Ethernet # 物理网卡名称
```

and `file2` is the file you want to apply the change to this will work for any text input using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR { new = (NR>1 ? new ORS : "") $0; next }
$1 == "dns:" { print new; f=1 }
$1 == "proxies:" { f=0 }
!f
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
   port: 6666
    socks-port: 6699
    redir-port: 6669
    allow-lan: true
    mode: Rule
    log-level: info
    external-controller: 0.0.0.0:9090

dns:
   enable: true
   enhanced-mode: redir-host # 或 fake-ip
   listen: 0.0.0.0:53
   nameserver:
      - 223.5.5.5
experimental:
   interface-name: Ethernet # 物理网卡名称
    proxies:
      - type: ss
        server: test.com

    proxy-groups:

      - name: Auto
        type: url-test
        proxies:
        - DATA:298.86GB DAYS:27

     - name: ⏲fallback
        type: fallback
        proxies:
        - DATA:298.86GB DAYS:27
```

or if you'd like to preserve the `file2` indenting:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR { new = (NR>1 ? new ORS : "") $0; next }
$1 == "dns:" {
    sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"")
    gsub(/(^|\n)/,"&"$0,new)
    print new
    f=1
}
$1 == "proxies:" { f=0 }
!f
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
   port: 6666
    socks-port: 6699
    redir-port: 6669
    allow-lan: true
    mode: Rule
    log-level: info
    external-controller: 0.0.0.0:9090

    dns:
       enable: true
       enhanced-mode: redir-host # 或 fake-ip
       listen: 0.0.0.0:53
       nameserver:
          - 223.5.5.5
    experimental:
       interface-name: Ethernet # 物理网卡名称
    proxies:
      - type: ss
        server: test.com

    proxy-groups:

      - name: Auto
        type: url-test
        proxies:
        - DATA:298.86GB DAYS:27

     - name: ⏲fallback
        type: fallback
        proxies:
        - DATA:298.86GB DAYS:27
```